# Typescript React - Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Appearance'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create some UI utility components with React Typescript. These utilities are meant to provide some default styling to HTML elements.

`FullScreen` is just a `<div>` whose height is `100vh` and whose width is `100vw`.

So I figured `FullSreenProps` should extend `HTMLDivElement`. But when I spread `props.style` into the style property, I get a type error:

```
Type '{ width: string; height: string; accentColor: string; alignContent: string; alignItems: string; alignSelf: string; alignmentBaseline: string; all: string; animation: string; animationDelay: string; ... 443 more ...; [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<...>; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Types of property 'appearance' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Appearance'.ts(2322)
```

Here's the `FullScreen` component:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';


interface FullScreenProps extends HTMLDivElement{}

const FullScreen = (props: FullScreenProps): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div
      {...props}
      style={
          {
            ...props.style,
            width: "100vw", 
            height: "100vh",
          }
      }
      >
      </div>
    );
}
export default FullScreen
```

What's the correct way to pass `props.style` while also specificying `height: 100vh` and `width: 100vw` in the `style` prop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HTMLDivElement` is the native browser interface for the `div` element. However, to use it as prop-type for react's `div`, you have to wrap it in `React.HTMLProps<...>` interface.

Coming to the `Omit` part, you need to omit `ref` because you cannot read `ref` from props. You need to use the `React.forwardRef` HOC and get it as a `second` argument to your Functional Component.

And, `as` is a special prop which we can use to replace the component. For eg. `<Typography as="h1">Hi there</Typography>` or `<Typography as="h4">Hi there</Typography>`, etc and in the `Typography` component, you can do the following:

```
const Typography = (props) => {
  const {as: Component, children, ...other} = props;
  return (
    <Component {...other}>{children}</Component>
  );
}
```

Now, if you want to use it in your component, then you can (don't omit it). But, be sure to remove it from `props` before spreading them into the `div` element as it is not accepted by `div`.

You can try the following:

```
import React from 'react';


interface FullScreenProps extends Omit<React.HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement>, 'as' | 'ref'> {}

const FullScreen = (props: FullScreenProps): JSX.Element => {
    return (
      <div
      {...props}
      style={
          {
            ...(props.style || {}),
            width: "100vw", 
            height: "100vh",
          }
      }
      >
      </div>
    );
}
export default FullScreen
```

Comment: This works! Any chance you could elaborate on your answer? Seems like we need to remove the ```as``` and ```ref``` props, but why?

Comment: Added explanation